# Contour plot in a specific form

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a contour plot in Mathematica. In normal and common case the plot will be shown in a square form but I want to have a plot in a triangle and a piece of circle form (disk-segment). How can I  figure it out?

Suppose I have the following contour plot:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

and I want to have the plot like the following figure.[image]

Thank you.

Comment: See `RegionFunction`

Comment: How can I use       RegionFunction    for a piece of a circular form or a triangle?

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Disk[{0, 0}, 4 , {0, \[Pi]/4.}], PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) for [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html)ing a [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) showing the desired polar region to get something close to the desired picture:

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] Cos[y], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 100, 
   MaxRecursion -> 5, ContourStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 300];
cp2 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 100, 
   MaxRecursion -> 5, ContourStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 300];
{pp1, pp2} = ParametricPlot[{v Cos[u], v Sin[u]}, {u, 0, Pi/4}, {v, .1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Texture[#], Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> False, Axes -> False] /. Opacity[_] :> Opacity[1] & /@ 
  {cp1, cp2};

Grid[{{"", Style[ContourPlot,20, "Panel", Bold], Style[ParametricPlot,20, "Panel", Bold]},
 {Rotate[Style[TraditionalForm[Cos[x] Cos[y]], 20, "Panel", Bold], Pi/2], cp1, pp1},
 {Rotate[Style[TraditionalForm[Cos[x] +  Cos[y]], 20, "Panel", Bold], Pi/2], cp2, pp2}}, 
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Use `{u, -Pi, Pi}`, and `{v, 0, 1}` in `ParametricPlot` above to get

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind the links I inserted, and +1 of course.

Comment: thank you @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 3):

by using `RegionFunction`:

```
(* in a sector *)
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic,
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 
                  0.5 <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 4 && 0. <= ArcTan[x, y] <= \[Pi]/4]]
```

[image]

```
(* in a triangle *)
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic,
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y <= x + 1 && y <= -3/4 x + 4 && y >= 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear José Antonio Díaz Navas, Thank you. It is what I wanted.

Comment: How can I change the angle between the axes from 90 to 45 degrees?
Actually, I want to fix the axes on the plot.

Comment: @HadiSobhani please elaborate your question. You mean you want the axes to be nonorthogonal?

Comment: Exactly. I want the axes to be nonorthogonal.